# Probability - Revealed/ Collapsed Options

Tags: probability, game-theory, bayes-theorem, card-games

A small puzzle.

There is a deck of $52$ cards. There is a $70\%$ chance a card at random has been replaced with the joker, and $30\%$ chance that a card has not. $51$ of the cards are flipped over, and the joker is not among them. You are handed the last card, what is the chance that you have the joker?

**My analysis:**

I originally thought that the probability would be $0.7 \times \frac{1}{52}$, but since the other $51$ cards have been turned over is it not just $70\%$?

Comment: Failing to find the joker among the first $51$ cards is evidence (not proof) that it isn't there.  Apply Bayes Theorem.

Comment: I should maybe clarify that the 52nd card can be a joker, as in the 52nd card may have been replaced with a joker. I think the number of cards is arbitrary. If I am incorrect, apologies. @lulu

Comment: I think your clarification confuses things.  In my first comment, I assumed that you started with an ordinary deck.  Then, either replaced a card with a Joker or not, then shuffled the deck so that the Joker, if there is one, could be in any position with equal probability.  If you meant something other than that, you should edit your post for clarity.

Comment: Apologies, editied for clarity @lulu.

Comment: "*edited for clarity*" did not in fact clarify the point that lulu was trying to make.  To clarify, the sentence you added should have read "*a card* **at random** *has been replaced with the joker*" or it should have read "**the last** *card has been replaced with the joker*" depending on which scenario you wish to explore.

Comment: This problem is very similar to other Bayes Theorem questions, including but not limited to the Monty Hall problem, the Boy-Girl problem, the question of if you have two coins where one is fair and the other has double-heads and you pick one at random and flip 10 heads in a row what the probability the next flip is also going to be heads, etc... This problem like all of these others is solved, as lulu already alluded to, by Bayes' Theorem.  It is not going to be $0.7$, it is not going to be $0.7\times \frac{1}{52}$, it will be a bit more involved than that, but it is a standard problem type.

Comment: Apologies @JMoravitz I will edit it to how you have specified, and will try and use your insight.

Comment: So... what do you know already about Bayes' Theorem?  It is usually defined in terms of events $A$ and $B$.  Let's also name some events here... what might we want to call "Event $A$"?  Can we find any probabilities?  Were any probabilities given to us in the problem statement?

Comment: I haven't exactly learned Bayes' Theorem yet, but I am reading the textbook to try and apply it to the situation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem, like so many others related to it, is approached by [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) which is a direct consequence of the definition of conditional probability, found by just rearranging the formula in the definition a bit.  From $\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)=\Pr(A\cap B)$ and similarly $\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\cap B)$, setting these equal and rearranging a bit we get:

$$\Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)}$$

As an intermediate step, it is common in these problems to have to rely on the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  In this context implying that $\Pr(B)=\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A^c\cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(B\mid A^c)$.

---

Now, as to your specific problem... let us begin by naming events and interpreting the problem statement.

Let $A$ be the event that there was in fact a joker mixed into the deck.  Then $A^c$ is the event that there was not a joker mixed into the deck.  We were told in the problem statement that $\Pr(A)=0.7$

Let $B$ be the event that the first $51$ cards were not jokers.

Recognize the probability you are after "*What is the probability that you will be handed a joker as the 52nd card given that the first 51 cards are all not jokers*" is precisely the probability $\Pr(A\mid B)$ since if there was a joker and the first 51 were not, the last card must be a joker, while if there was not a joker shuffled into the deck then clearly the 52nd card wouldn't be a joker either.  (*We could have been more careful and used a third event name talking about the 52nd card, but I don't feel that is necessary here*)

Now, we should be able to intuit the values of $\Pr(B\mid A)$ and $\Pr(B\mid A^c)$, the probabilities that we in fact would have had the first 51 cards all not be the joker in the event that there had or had not been a joker added to the deck respectively in the first place.

> $\Pr(B\mid A) = \dfrac{1}{52}$ since if there was a joker, it would have needed to be shuffled into the last spot. $\Pr(B\mid A^c)=1$ since if there was no joker, it is guaranteed we would not have found any jokers.

Next, we should have enough information to find $\Pr(B)$.

> $\Pr(B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(B\mid A^c)=0.7\cdot \dfrac{1}{52}+0.3$ by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and using the values found earlier

Finally, finish the problem by [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) to find $\Pr(A\mid B)$.

> $\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)} = \dfrac{0.7\cdot \frac{1}{52}}{0.7\cdot \frac{1}{52}+0.3}\approx 0.04294\dots$

Comment: Re: "*we could have used a third event name... but I don't feel that is necessary here*" A worthwhile exercise to take this problem a step further might be to have been handed only 50 of the 52 cards and to be asked what the probability should be that the 51st card is a joker or not given that the first 50 were not.  At that point it wouldn't simply be $\Pr(A\mid B)$ any more and we would have had to do a bit more bookkeeping.  I challenge you to try to finish that version.  There should only be one or two extra steps needed beyond what I showed here.